# Does Linq.First() method return the first entry of a SortedDictionary in O(1) in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, time-complexity, sorteddictionary

I know the `Last()` method of Linq returns the last entry of a `SortedDictionary` in O(n) because it needs to enumerate through all the entries. What about the `First()` method? Is it O(1) since it's enumerating only one iteration?

Comment: For the unconditional `First` it's very likely to be O(1) (subject to the `SortedDictionary` internals), but the predicated `First` can have a worst case of O(n), in case no item matches the predicate.

Comment: `SortedDictionary` is implemented as a red-black tree so will have to traverse O(ln N) nodes to reach the minimum value returned by `First`.

Comment: I see, but doesn't the Linq.Min() method search for the min value in O(ln N)? I mean, the SortedDictionary.Keys returns a reference to the key collection of the dictionary in O(1), then I was thinking the Linq.First() method can return the first index of Key Collection in O(1). So, once I call Linq.First() method, it grabs the Key Collection internally and returns the first index of the collection.